# How do i design a high pass filters in MATLAB without using the builtin function?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

i'm just not sure how to draw the frequency response (H) of the high pass filter? after drawing the frequency response I can get the b coefficient by taking the ifft of (H).
So yeah, for a low pass filter, with a cutoff frequency of say pi/2 : the frequency response code will be `H = exp(-1*j*w*4).*(((0 <= w) & (w<= pi/2)) | ((2*pi - pi/2 <= w) & (w<=2*pi));`
since the response is "1" between 0 and pi/2 and between (2*pi - pi/2) and 2*pi. 
Can you help me write H for a high pass filter?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a low-pass filter with frequency response `H_lp(w)`, you can find a corresponding high-pass filter `H_hp(w)` by subtracting its frequency response from 1.

```
H_hp(w) = 1 - H_lp(w)
```

So if you want your high-pass filter to pass from `K` to `pi`, design a low-pass, which you already know how to do, that passes from `0` to `K`, then use the equation above to find the high-pass frequency response, and then take the IFFT of `H_hp`.

Comment: Sort of.  This will give you the complementary response, which may or may not be what you're after.  See my answer, which involves translating the low-pass prototype up to Nyquist.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the impulse response, `b[n]`, of a low-pass filter, you can convert it to an equivalent high-pass filter by mixing up to the Nyquist frequency.  You do this by multiplying with a complex exponential: `exp(j*pi*n)`.  However, this is very easy, as this is simply the sequence `+1, -1, +1, -1, ...`.  Therefore, simply multiply every other sample of `b[n]` by -1.

Comment: +1, this is by far the easier way to go.  It works for IIR filters too - multiply the numerator coefficients by `+1, -1, +1, ...` and the denominator coefficients by `-1, +1, -1, ...`.